# While selecting values from a drop down, value are shown in a text box

Tags: php, mysql, jquery

I'll try my level best by using AJAX, but I'm not able to get this to work.

I have 5 select boxes and 5 text boxes, and when I select the first drop down its value is shown in a text box and so on with the other text boxes.

I have been trying this:

```
ajax: {
        url: 'help/ajax_help.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {help: function(){return $(this).attr('id');}},               
      },
```

Taking the current value of the dropdown, but it is not working.

Please help me.

Thanks and Regards.

Comment: Where does it fail, does it work for any of the dropdown boxes? And please add more of your code than that.

Comment: What does `ajax_help.php` return? How do you process the response?

Comment: ...and what exactly is your goal? Are you trying to post the value of one select-box? Or the ones from the text-boxes? Both? What are you having trouble with? Getting the value or sending it?

Comment: i want to fetch the value of multiple box ex when i am selecting value from first dropdown then its going to search the value from database then return something and echo in tectbox

Answer (score 0):

```
ajax: {
        url: 'help/ajax_help.php',
        type: 'GET',
        data: $(this).val(),
      },
```

Does that work?